# Chrome large scaled object in 3d object disappears

Tags: google-chrome, rendering, scale, translate3d

I don't know if this is a bug or if it just needs to be called a rendering issue, but it's annoying.

If you have a 3d translated object, within that you have a scaled object, if that scaled object exceeds a certain size it just disappears. This is what I mean: http://dabblet.com/gist/4563584 (hover the a and wait to see it disappear)

I googled and searched a lot, but to no avail.

You might think: *why?* Because I am making an impress.js slideshow, and it needs to zoom a lot, but when using 3d transforms to hardware accelerate, object are cached as an images to save memory or something, I get that, but the big one is still visible when completely zoomed in, and it gets blurry (because it's cached at a small size), scaling and zooming out fixes that problem, but then it disappears...

I haven't found any other way to fix the blurry text issues without the scale, any help on that is also welcome.

- Using google chrome 24.0.1312.52
- Firefox 16.0.2 is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it's a Chrome bug, doesn't happen in Firefox/IE/Safari. Been around for a while.

The issue has been reported to Chromium several times, here's the most recent one:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=337493

Comment: This issue seems to be fixed in Chrome 37.0.2062.68 beta-m (64-bit).